# Android: Cant replace fragment inside activity with another fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and having some issues with replacing a fragment with another fragment.

In my `MainFragment.java`, the first thing I do in `onCreate` is check for internet connectivity, and if there is not, I replace that fragment with the `InternetCheckFragment`. However, in `InternetCheckFragment.java`, when I try to inflate my `check_internet.xml`, the app closes, but there is no error.

activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.ui.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ui.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends VerticalGridFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isConnectedToInternet() == true)
        {
            // DO stuff
        }
        else
        {
            showInternetError();
        }
    }

    public void showInternetError()
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.show_internet_error , new InternetCheckFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    ....
}
```

InternetCheckFragment.java:

```
public class InternetCheckFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_internet, parent, false);
    }
}
```

check_internet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/show_internet_error"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_retry"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="RETRY"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, I'm getting the error `No view found for id`.

I'm sure I'm not setting something correctly? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh!..it was a stupid mistake, I replaced `R.id.show_internet_error` within `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.show_internet_error , new InternetCheckFragment()).commit();` with `R.id.main_browse_fragment` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating a Fragment in a Fragment using the Fragment's FragmentManager.
This FragmentManager cannot handle this.

Try using the `SupportFragmentManager` with `AppCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` and the support Fragments from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`